# IInAppBillingService.java does not generate Java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am following this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission

No InAppBillingActivity file is generating. I'm not sure why. I checked to make sure everything is placed correctly but no luck. Here is what my folder structure looks like:
[Click this for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTQW.png)

Now I know there are similar questions like this but none of them were able to solve my problem. I have already imported googles billing library as well. No file generates when I run / build the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the docs are not very accurate in specifying where it is that you will find the java file that should be in the gen folder. I had faced the same problem and had broken my head over it, until I found that the .java file was infact generated and it was in the path :

> \app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.java

Its not a headache issue and your code runs smoothly itself without any interventions required. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It was right there for me too. Accepted as answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: Awesome! That is much better explanation than in Android docs!

Answer (score 1):

In android studio double click on your package name:

[image]

click in New and then on AIDL

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: I created a video to show you what I'm doing because it is still not working. Is there anything else wrong? https://youtu.be/TwpnzKS6sGo

Comment: There is no generated InnAppBillingService.java in a gen/ folder like there is supposed to be

Comment: I dont know what the docs mean by gen folder, i have implemented it just like you did in many apps in the play store, it works that way

Answer (score 0):

Its usually generated but not put where the tutorial tells you. If you do a Ctrl+N and type in the class name in intelliJ you may be able to find it